# Fail to set JWT token in PAW, works for POSTMAN

Tags: jwt, paw-app, django-rest-auth

I was able to send a request with a JWT token in header using POSTMAN, I'd like to switch to use Paw, but it returned with error

> Authentication credentials were not provided.

Below is what I tried for the Authorization header:

**Postman (this works)**

```
Authorization: JWT [token]
```

**Paw**

1. `Authorization: Bearer [token]`
2. `Authorization: JWT [token]`
3. `Authorization: [token]`
4. `Authorization: Token [token]`

Any idea please?

Comment: Hey @April, we've done some research about JWTs and it seems like JWTs are independent of the rest of the request. Your option (2) `Authorization : JWT [token]` should be working fine. Any additional info you can share that would help us solve this? You can email us details to support@luckymarmot.com thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MichaMazaheri for the quick feedback! I think I got it figured out, using option (2) Authorization : JWT [token] and then on options, I checked on Follow Redirects, Redirect Authorization and Redirect Original Method. Then the request made through!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked out! Yes, Postman doesn't give you control on the redirections, so if you have a redirect it will just follow it. Whereas Paw doesn't follow redirects by default (as a debug tool we believe it's the expected behavior to see exactly what's happening). Hope it helps :)

Comment: @April Please post your comment as answer and approve it. Thanks.